# How to append query string to pagination links using Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination, query-string, laravel-blade

Hello and thanks for your help. I've done some research and tried a few options but can't seem get this to work properly.  I'm passing a URL with a query string into a function that loads the page via URL passed. However, I'm trying to find a way to paginate the results as well.  Is there a way I can pass the query string url to Laravel's pagination links? Thanks.

My URL with query string

```
            <a id="searchData"class="btn btn-primary ml-1 mr-5 text-light" title="Search" type="submit" 
        onclick="ajaxLoad('{{url('dma/data')}}?startDate='+$('#startDate').val()+'&endDate='+$('#endDate').val() 
            + '&dmaNameFilter=' + encodeURI(dma_name) + '&memberNameFilter=' + encodeURI(member_name))">Search Results
        </a>
```

I tried this for the links():

```
{{ $data->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

I have this in my Controller:

```
$data = Report::where('CallDate', '>=', $start_date)->where('CallDate', '<=', $end_date)->paginate(13)->appends(request()->query());
```

Comment: If you are sure `request()->query()` is an array with startDate/endDate / dmaNameFilter / memberNameFilter, your pagination links in blade is OK. But it seems incorrect in the controller which I think you should add more where conditions for the query, e.g. dmaNameFilter, memberNameFilter,...

Answer (score 3):

You can also add this:

```
$this->app->resolving(\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::class, function ($paginator) {
   return $paginator->appends(Arr::except(request()->query(), $paginator->getPageName()));
});
```

To your AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$data->appends(request()->input())->links()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 8, You can simply use

```php
$paginator->withQueryString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any data to pagination by calling

```php
{{ $paginator->links('view.name', ['foo' => 'bar']) }}
```

on your situation I think you want to pass query string to paginator; you may try

```php
{{ $paginator->links('view.name', request()->getQueryString() ) }}
```

If you need to append querystrings for your ajax controller you'd better check https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a try. Thank you for your help.